# Google App maker mobile and browser compatibility

Tags: google-app-maker

App maker sample projects are working perfectly in mobiles, forms and tables are adjusted perfectly to the mobile view. But whatever we developed in app maker the designs are not adjusted to mobile layouts they are still in the desktop view. Is there any option to configure the application to work in mobile.

Our application is not working correctly in safari is that any browser compatibility issue from app maker or it is the issue from our side.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Flow and Layout sections along with Panels to make sure your widgets group/resize/align correctly when resizing the screen.  You can test this easily in chrome by pressing F12 and toggling the device toolbar (Ctrl-Shift-M or the 2 mobile devices icon at the top of the sidebar).

Read up on CSS Flexbox to understand how the Flow section works.  With a combination of Fill Parent and Fit to Content in layout, using horizontal/vertical Panels, and grouping your widgets in Panels, along with using the Flexbox features, you should be able to get your screen to accommodate desktop and varying sized mobiles.  It definitely takes some time to get the right combination though.

Comment: Is that how the App maker sample projects has been implemented.